# Counting length of list inside of list

Tags: python, list

I am trying to use the number of items inside of a list that is inside of another list to make a bar chart, however, when I try to count the length of each individual list inside of that list, i get NameError: name 'no' is not defined

```
mesasnovio = [[no,nope,yes],[a,b,c,d],[f,g,h,i],[j,k,l,m],[s,t]]
print (len(mesasnovio[1]))
```

I want it to be able to show me the length

```
>>> 3
```

Comment: no, nope, and yes are strings, encase them in quotes: `["no", "nope", "yes"]`

Answer (score 1):

You missed `''`.

```
mesasnovio = [['no','nope','yes'],['a','b','c','d'],['f','g','h','i'],['j','k','l','m'],['s','t']]

print (len(mesasnovio[1]))
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to wrap all of your strings in quotations.

```
mesasnovio = [['no','nope','yes'],['a','b','c','d'],['f','g','h','i'],['j','k','l','m'],['s','t']]
```

Answer (score 1):

Also, because lists are zero-indexed in Python, mesasnovio[1] refers to ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'].  So you will get a length of 4, not 3.

Answer (score 1):

Here is one way using `map` to get all `len` of `list` inside your `list`

```
lenl=list(map(len,mesasnovio))
lenl
Out[595]: [3, 4, 4, 4, 2]

lenl[0]
3
```

Answer (score 0):

Others have addressed your issue with not encapsulating your `strings`, but if you would like the length of all inner lists

```
lengths = list(map(len, mesasnovio))
```